# Como remover o margin top do ImageView

Tags: android

Olá, estou a criar um app, e tenho uma ImageView com o id ivthumb que fica no topo mas por algum motivo ela não cola no topo e fica um espacinho. Alguém me pode ajudar a resolver este problema? PS: Eu removo a Action Bar com getSupportActionBar().hide(); caso tenha alguma coisa a ver com isso.

Imagem:

https://ibb.co/QJLFFsD

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#15202b"
        android:padding="0dip"
        tools:context=".ViewMateria">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivthumb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="232dp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="237dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="37dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9sp"
                android:onClick="voltar"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="501dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="230sp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvvtitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="23sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvdesc"
                        android:layout_width="399dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique alinhamento da sua `ImageView`. Utilizando a propriedade [`layout_alignParentTop`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentTop)`= true` você vai garantir que o topo do componente ficará ligado ao topo do seu layout pai. Caso a margem continue a aparecer, altere o [`scaleType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType)) para `centerCrop`, de modo a preencher toda a superfície da ImageView com o conteúdo da imagem, mantendo a proporção.

Se isso ainda não resolver, use o [LayoutInspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) para investigar as propriedades de tamanho e posicionamento da sua ImageView em runtime.

Ao desenvolver interfaces, tome cuidado ao definir tamanhos fixos para componentes, pois isso pode dificultar a composição da tela, especialmente quando há uma variação muito grande no tamanho dos dispositivos que executarão o aplicativo. Dê preferência à utilização do `match_parent` e `wrap_content`, ou ainda, use o `ConstraintLayout` para definir tamanhos e proporções mais dinâmicas.